# Ramp and Hold Users for Some time and Ramp again

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I have the following scenario to be load tested for a service and it does not seem to work as expected. My scenario is as follows.

- Test with `rampUsers(100)` over `15 minutes duration`
- Hold the users for about 10 minutes `holdFor(10 minutes)`
- Then again `rampUsers(200)` over `15 minutes duration`
- Hold the users for about 10 minutes `holdFor(10 minutes)`
- Then again `rampUsers(200)` over `15 minutes duration`

I am trying to use `throttle` option for this but it does not seem to work as expected
here is my code snippets combinations that I have tried so far

```
//NUM_USERS = 300
//DURATION = 15 minutes
//CONSTANT_DURATION = 5 minutes
// Tried with different combinations of NUM_USERS and DURATION but not helpful

scn.inject(
      rampUsers(NUM_USERS*1) during DURATION,
      constantUsersPerSec(1) during CONSTANT_DURATION,
      rampUsers(NUM_USERS*2) during DURATION,
      constantUsersPerSec(2) during CONSTANT_DURATION,
      rampUsers(NUM_USERS*3) during DURATION,
      constantUsersPerSec(3) during CONSTANT_DURATION
)

scn.inject(
          rampUsers(NUM_USERS) during DURATION
        ).throttle(
          reachRps(NUM_USERS/4) in (CONSTANT_DURATION),
          holdFor(CONSTANT_DURATION),
          jumpToRps(NUM_USERS/3),
          holdFor(CONSTANT_DURATION),
          jumpToRps(NUM_USERS/2),
          holdFor(CONSTANT_DURATION)
)

scn.inject(
      rampUsers(NUM_USERS) during DURATION
    ).throttle(
        holdFor(CONSTANT_DURATION),
        reachRps(NUM_USERS+NUM_USERS) in (DURATION+DURATION),
        holdFor(CONSTANT_DURATION)
)
```

Can any one help on this which one works in this case. I would like to have a graph like this
[image]

Comment: your graph is in requests per second, but your initial description seems to be in relation to users - what are you after?

Comment: The graph is just for easy understanding.. no relationship with the use case..  you can ignore the labels

Comment: so you want to target concurrent users? Your script doesn't reflect that

Comment: I want to hold the user not the concurrent user scenario.. Want to reach to some level of users and maintain that level for some time..

Answer (score 0):

To target *injection rate* as you stated you want in the comments, you need something like this

```
scn.inject(
  rampUsersPerSec(0) to (300) during DURATION,
  constantUsersPerSec(300) during CONSTANT_DURATION,
  rampUsersPerSec(300) to (600) during DURATION,
  constantUsersPerSec(600) during CONSTANT_DURATION,
  ...
)
```